I am trying to set up xampp/laravel/mysql for my project, but I am getting error that says Illuminate\Database\QueryException
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp> php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'laravel.migrations' doesn't exist in engine (SQL: select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }

  i   A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your database migrations.
      https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:414
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'laravel.migrations' doesn't exist in engine")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:414
      PDO::prepare("select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc")
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp>

After running the above command I am getting this kind of message. I tried to look for password of the Database but it was empty nothing was there.
Please help

This has nothing to do with mysql or mysql passwords. Laravel migration table does not exists for whatever reason

Does this answer your question? Laravel migrations table not found

check your .env file
and match the database value
